# Selecting all elements that only one of their associated value is not in a predefined list

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**Note**: I had a hard time choosing a title for this question. I am not sure it describes accurately what I want, so I will be grateful if instead of a downvote you will help to improve the title. :)

---

I have a table with the following structure:

```
log:
+-----+-----+
| uid | uip | <- user id and user ip
+-----+-----+
```

I also have a table with some predefined user id's:

```
predfined_users:
+-----+
| uid |
+-----+
|  1  |
-------
|  2  |
-------
|  3  |
-------
```

**What I am trying to achieve:**

My "algorithm" should find all the `uip` that the result of the following steps for them is 1:

1. Collect from `log` all distinct users which are associated with the `uip`
2. Count how many of the users are NOT in the `predfined_users` table.

**Example:**

Let's say this is the list of the users that are associated with the IP address `1.0.0.0`:

```
+-----+
| uid |
+-----+
|  1  |
-------
|  3  |
-------
|  7  |
```

Only one of these values is not in `predfined_users` (7), so `1.0.0.0` should be returned. I want to select all the `uip` that satisfy this as well, meaning, only one of the `uid` associated with them is not in `predfined_users`. Also, it is worth noting that if a `uip` is associated only with one `uid`, then the query should not return it.

**What I have already tried**

Here is my general idea but I am not sure what to write instead of the `???` or even if I am in the right direction:

```
SELECT [uip]
FROM log
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT [uid]
        FROM log WHERE [uip] = ???
    )a
    WHERE uid NOT IN (
        SELECT uid
        from predfined_users
    ) 
)=1
```

Comment: You can just make it simple, sample data for those two tables and the expected results with your code :)

Comment: @Sami - I am not sure what you mean... Could you please elaborate? :)

Comment: Could you please create a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017) and post the link in your question and also the expected results?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
select l.uip, count(distinct l.uid)
from log l left join
     predefined_users pu
     on l.uid = pu.uid
where pu.uid is null
group by l.uip;
```

Comment: Thanks! I am not sure this is working properly. I am also getting IP addresses which more than one of the users associated with them is not in the predefined list.

Comment: @Sipo I think you simply need to add to the end *having count(distinct l.uid) = 1*

Comment: Worth saying that all the IP's are associated with no more than 10 users. Your code returns a result with an IP column and the amount of users it is associated with that are not in the predefined list column, which is great. This is why I was surprised that when I truncated `predefined_users` (to replcae them with a new list) and run your code while the table was empty, I still got some IP's that were associated with less then 10 users. How is this possible? The logic is that we count the users that are not in the list, but if the list is empty then it should be all of them! Meaning 10!

Comment: @Sipo . . . If you want to filter the list to those ips with 10 or more users, you would need to add `having count(distinct l.uid) >= 10)`.  That is not part of the question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this query to retrieve the uips that having only one associated uid which does not exist in table predfined_users:

```
Select distinct uip from [dbo].[Log]
where uid not in(Select uid from predfined_users)
group by uip
having count(uip) = 1
```

if you want to retrieve the uips which have associations which do not exist, regardless of the count of irrelevant uids, you can use this code:

```
Select distinct  uip from [dbo].[Log]
where uid not in(Select uid from predfined_users)
```